# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow Error

Tags: vb.net, memory, byte, integer-overflow

```
      IntPtr(MemInfo.BaseAddress)

    End While
End Sub
```

The error is caused by the `+ mem1.RegionSize` part in this line:

This is part of my memory scanner in VB.net
I have read something about changing `ToInt32` to `ToInt64` but that still didn't solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the proper way of adding an offset to an `IntPtr`. It provides the [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for doing that. I am assuming that you are already marshaling the `BaseAddress` field of the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure as an `IntPtr`.

So you should change your code to

```
Addy = IntPtr.Add(MemInfo.BaseAddress, MemInfo.RegionSize);
```

Comment: Got an error on that : "Argument not specified for parameter 'offset' of 'Public Shared Function Add(pointer As System.IntPtr, offset As Integer) As System.IntPtr" and yes BaseAddress is set to IntPtr

Comment: @virtualmind updated, a dumb error. `IntPtr.Add` is a static function on `IntPtr`.